# What's the difference between `pipenv install` and `pipenv lock`?

Tags: python, pipenv, pipfile

Given that a Pipfile exists, it seems that both would install all dependencies from the Pipfile, and update Pipfile.lock. So, what is the difference?

Comment: `pipenv lock` *doesn't* (I think) install any dependencies. It simply generates `Pipfile.lock` from your `Pipfile`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can have the details in the documentation:
https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics

Basically `pipenv install` installs all the packages in the environment, whereas `pipenv lock` creates the pipenv.lock file depending on what is already installed (even if you initialized your environment with a requirements.txt file using pip)

If your folder is empty the effect will indeed be the same: the initialization of a pipenv environment with the default packages

Comment: Ok, I see where I got confused. When you add a dependency to Pipfile and then run Pipfile.lock, this dependency propagates to Pipfile.lock. I thought, it means that it actually gets installed. But it doesn't. Which, IMHO, is a strange behavior. I end up with a package in Pipfile and in Pipfile.lock but not in the system.

Comment: I downvoted because that is not what I find happens. I see what @chepner said: it generates `Pipfile.lock` from `Pipfile` but wihout installing dependencies.

Answer (score 8):

`pipenv lock` generates a consistent set of dependencies from `Pipfile` and writes that to `Pipfile.lock`. It doesn't change the installed packages.

`pipenv install` with no arguments would generate the same set of dependencies **and** install them into the virtualenv.

I find the Pipenv documentation unclear.